Can a new transaction claim an older sequence id?
I'm using a PostgresSQL database as an eventstore. We used to use https://github.com/SQLStreamStore/SQLStreamStore
But they had issues when having a lot of parallel transactions.
Essentially we suffered from a lot of 'skipped' events.
A similar problem is explained here: https://github.com/eugene-khyst/postgresql-event-sourcing?tab=readme-ov-file#transactional-outbox-using-transaction-id
So together with a co-worker we decided to fork the library and implement it using pg_current_snapshot().
We had a few iterations of this but in the end we got it working:
https://github.com/ArneSchoonvliet/SQLStreamStore
So the main idea is, if we see a gap in between positions we will only trust the events with a lower transaction_id than 'xmin'.
This has worked great for us. And most problems are solved.
But sometimes we have a weird occurrence
Position    MessageId                               CreatedAt                       TransactionId
31170300    be7b412a-103c-5cdd-8458-57fbb0e5c39e    2024-09-29 13:23:27.733 +0200   2306832989
31170299    38b9d7d9-540c-5440-a2a0-10b91cffb2ad    2024-09-29 13:23:27.736 +0200   2306832990

Query result
Position: 31170297, Array index: 0, Transaction id: 2306832974
Position: 31170298, Array index: 1, Transaction id: 2306832976
Position: 31170300, Array index: 2, Transaction id: 2306832989
Xmin: 2306832990

In the query result you see that 31170299 is missing. So our 'gap checking' code kicks in. And will check if all transactions_ids are lower than xmin. In this case they are...
31170299 wasn't visible yet.
So as a result that event will be skipped.
Question
Is it expected that this can happen. A newer transaction claiming a lower seq value?
We are using Google Cloud managed pgsql db
Since I don't really know how we would ever be able to detect that without checking every time if transactions are still happening. But this would impact performance since we would lose a lot of time with 'actual' gaps (caused by transactions that are rolled back)
People probably wonder what the insert / query sql looks like
INSERT:
https://github.com/ArneSchoonvliet/SQLStreamStore/blob/master/src/SqlStreamStore.Postgres/PgSqlScripts/AppendToStream.sql
Important part:
INSERT INTO __schema__.messages (message_id,
                                 stream_id_internal,
                                 stream_version,
                                 created_utc,
                                 type,
                                 json_data,
                                 json_metadata,
                                 transaction_id)
SELECT m.message_id, _stream_id_internal, _current_version + (row_number()
    over ()) :: int, _created_utc, m.type, m.json_data, m.json_metadata, pg_current_xact_id()
FROM unnest(_new_stream_messages) m
ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING;
GET DIAGNOSTICS _success = ROW_COUNT;

As you can see the position isn't set. This is because it's an autoincrement defined like this:
"position" int8 DEFAULT nextval('messages_seq'::regclass) NOT NULL

QUERY:
https://github.com/ArneSchoonvliet/SQLStreamStore/blob/master/src/SqlStreamStore.Postgres/PgSqlScripts/ReadAll.sql
Important part:
BEGIN
  OPEN _txinfo FOR
  SELECT pg_snapshot_xmin(pg_current_snapshot());
  RETURN NEXT _txinfo;
    
  OPEN _messages FOR
  WITH messages AS (
      SELECT __schema__.streams.id_original,
             __schema__.messages.message_id,
             __schema__.messages.stream_version,
             __schema__.messages.position,
             __schema__.messages.created_utc,
             __schema__.messages.type,
             __schema__.messages.transaction_id,
             __schema__.messages.json_metadata,
             __schema__.messages.json_data,
             __schema__.streams.max_age
      FROM __schema__.messages
             INNER JOIN __schema__.streams ON __schema__.messages.stream_id_internal = __schema__.streams.id_internal
      WHERE  __schema__.messages.position >= _position
      ORDER BY __schema__.messages.position
      LIMIT _count
  )
  SELECT * FROM messages LIMIT _count;
  RETURN NEXT _messages;
END;



Is it expected that this can happen. A newer transaction claiming a lower seq value?

Yes.
The formulation "claiming a lower seq value" is fuzzy. You seem to be thinking "writing a lower sequence number to a table row". But that's already beyond the reach of a SEQUENCE.
What a SEQUENCE guarantees
(Also addressing the discussion in comments.)
Retrieving numbers from a sequence happens strictly sequentially, as the name implies - with some notable exceptions:

Manual intervention. Users with sufficient privileges can manipulate the SEQUENCE object any way they wish.
Wraparound. Typically an unlikely event, even for integer number space. Near impossible for the vast realm of bigint - except, again, after manual intervention or code bugs of colossal proportions. You would be able to tell a wraparound when looking at it.
Sequences with a cache setting greater than 1.

There is an example in the manual:

For example, with a cache setting of 10, session A might
reserve values 1..10 and return nextval=1, then session B might
reserve values 11..20 and return nextval=11 before session A has
generated nextval=2. Thus, with a cache setting of one it is
safe to assume that nextval values are generated sequentially; with
a cache setting greater than one you should only assume that
the nextval values are all distinct, not that they are generated
purely sequentially.

Bold emphasis mine.
BUT that's beyond the point
For one, the time when a sequence number is issued is not strictly bound to the time when (or if) it will be written. The way can be long and winding. Doesn't even have to be in the same transaction if client code is written that way. nextval() can be called manually, a PROCEDURE or an anonymous code block with nested COMMIT, ...
More importantly, transactions draw numbers largely independent of when they started. Just because one started earlier does not mean it draws from the sequence earlier. Of course, later transactions can write earlier sequence numbers, or in your terms, a newer transaction can claim lower seq values.
The whole idea falls flat at the most basic level.

A sequence is a simple number generator. When you ask for a number, it gives you a new one. Unless you mess with the settings of the sequence or use a wraparound, you will never ever get a number that has been used by other transactions.
You can have hundreds of concurrent transactions asking for a number and each one gets a different number

The only guarantee a sequence provides is that every call to nextval() returns a value different from others, and even that only until the sequence wraps around. There's no guarantee that the values will be emitted in any particular order or that there will be no gaps in the sequence. For example, if a session obtains the next sequence value but then rolls back the transaction, the value will still be consumed (i.e. never emitted again).

Yeah I know. And those rollbacked commits cause real gaps and that's why we can never rely on the fact there won't be gaps. "if a session obtains the next sequence value but then rolls back the transaction, the value will still be consumed (i.e. never emitted again)."
Exactly and this is why I don't understand why a newer transaction (with a bigger transaction id) gets hold of an older sequence. Since if it was already used it should never appear again.

I don't know how exactly you define a "newer transaction" but neither the earlier start nor the earlier end of a transaction will guarantee that you get a lower sequence number.

"I don't know how exactly you define a "newer transaction""
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/transaction-id.html
Since I'm using pg_current_xact_id () is should already assign a transaction id. And that one is guaranteed incremental. What I actually think would solve my issue. Is to do the following:
Instead of doing the pg_current_xact_id() in the insert and the auto increment as default value is already getting those values store it, Then do the insert and using those values. Like this: https://pastebin.com/DJK9b7cq

@ErazerBrecht I'm not a PostgreSQL expert but a quick read on what pg_current_xact_id() is makes me think that's not the most reliable thing to be using either, and possibly could be part of your problem. The docs say the following things which make it worrisome to me 1. "If executed in a subtransaction, this will return the top-level transaction ID" and 2. "Note that the order in which transactions perform their first database write might be different from the order in which the transactions started". It sounds like there are cases where order can't be guaranteed and dupes can occur.
